# How to place an image into a specific Layout on Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to make a progress barrar for my game, in which a witch approaches a cauldron with each success of the player.

The problem is that I am not able to get the witch and the cauldron into the corresponding BoxLayout. They should be in the BoxLayout with id "progreso", however they appear in the lower left corner.

.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.behaviors.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.core.image import Image
kivy.require('1.0.6')

from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from random import choice, random
from kivy.properties import *
from kivy.graphics import *
import os
import random

FX_REFLEJO_VERTICAL = 1
FX_REFLEJO_HORIZONTAL = 2
FX_ESCALADO = 3
FX_NONE = 4

FXs_fase1 = [FX_REFLEJO_VERTICAL, FX_REFLEJO_HORIZONTAL, FX_ESCALADO]
FXs_fase3 = [FX_REFLEJO_VERTICAL, FX_REFLEJO_HORIZONTAL]

def busca_letra_img(letra):
    directorio = "data/img/letra_%s" % letra
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(directorio) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directorio, f))]
    img = choice(files)
    return os.path.join(directorio, img)

def letra_img_burbuja(letra):
    return "data/img/letra_%s/burbuja_may/%s.png" % (letra, letra)

def abecedario_sin(letra):
    abecedario = list("abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz")
    # extrae la letra seleccionada
    letra_idx = abecedario.index(letra)
    abecedario.pop(letra_idx)
    return list(abecedario)

# Selecciona siempre la letra y 9 mas
def selecciona_letras(letra_sel):
    abecedario = list("abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz")
    letras = []
    # extrae la letra seleccionada
    letra_idx = abecedario.index(letra_sel)
    abecedario.pop(letra_idx)
    # selecciona las 9 restantes aleatoriamente
    random.shuffle(abecedario)
    letras.extend(abecedario[0:9])
    # evita que la primera letra sea siempre la primera de la list
    # random.shuffle(letras)
    return letras

class BrujaProgreso(Widget):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BrujaProgreso, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.18, "center_y": 0.5}
        
class Target(Widget):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Target, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.9, "center_y": 0.5}

class ButOpcion(Widget):
    
    letra_img = StringProperty()
    efecto = OptionProperty("None", options=[FX_REFLEJO_VERTICAL, FX_REFLEJO_HORIZONTAL, FX_ESCALADO, FX_NONE])

    def __init__(self, letra_img, **kwargs):
        super(ButOpcion, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas.before:
            PushMatrix()
            self.rotate_ins = Rotate(angle=0) # template for future rotations
            self.scale_ins = Scale(1, 1, 1)

        with self.canvas.after:
            PopMatrix()

        def update_ins(w, center):
            self.rotate_ins.origin = center
            self.scale_ins.origin = center
        self.bind(center=update_ins)

        # esta tiene que estar al final porque modifica el efecto
        # que a su vez accede a las rotate_ins y scale_ins
        self.letra_img = letra_img

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if not self.parent: return
        ccaza = self.parent.parent.parent
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self == ccaza.intruso:
            ccaza.siguiente()

    def on_letra_img(self, instance, letra):
        # al inicializar la letra, vuelve al tamnyo original
        self.efecto = FX_NONE

    def on_efecto(self, instance, efecto):
        #print("Efecto: %d" % (efecto))
        if   efecto == FX_REFLEJO_VERTICAL:
            self.rotate_ins.angle = 180
            self.rotate_ins.axis: (1, 0, 0)
            self.scale_ins.xyz = (1, 1, 1)
        elif efecto == FX_REFLEJO_HORIZONTAL:
            self.rotate_ins.angle = 180
            self.rotate_ins.axis: (0, 1, 0)
            self.scale_ins.xyz = (1, 1, 1)
        elif efecto == FX_ESCALADO:
            self.rotate_ins.angle = 0
            self.scale_ins.xyz = (0.7, 0.7, 0.7)
        else: # None
            self.rotate_ins.angle = 0
            self.scale_ins.xyz = (1, 1, 1)



class ContainerCaza(Screen):

    # el juego consta de 3 fases
    fase = NumericProperty()
    # cada fase tiene 3 repeticiones
    repeticion = NumericProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ContainerCaza, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.intruso = None

    def enter_game(self):
        grid = self.ids["grid"]
        if not grid.children:
            # crea los botones con una letra por defecto
            letra_img = busca_letra_img("a")
            for n in range(0,4):
                but = ButOpcion(letra_img)
                grid.add_widget(but)
        
        progreso = self.ids["progreso"]
        brujita = BrujaProgreso()
        caldero = Target()
        progreso.add_widget(brujita)
        progreso.add_widget(caldero)
        
        self.fase = 1
        self.repeticion = 1

    def leave_game(self):
        pass
        
    def siguiente(self):
        if self.repeticion < 3:
            self.repeticion = self.repeticion + 1
        else:
            # pasamos de fase
            if self.fase < 3:
                self.fase = self.fase + 1
                self.repeticion = 1
            # termina el juego
            else:
                self.fase = 0
                self.repeticion = 0
                self.ids["grid"].clear_widgets()

    def on_fase(self, instance, fase):
        if   fase == 0: return
        elif fase == 1: self.fase_1()
        elif fase == 2: self.fase_2()
        elif fase == 3: self.fase_3()

    def on_repeticion(self, instance, repeticion):
        if repeticion == 0: return
        else:
            if   self.fase == 1: self.fase_1_repeticion(repeticion)
            elif self.fase == 2: self.fase_2_repeticion(repeticion)
            elif self.fase == 3: self.fase_3_repeticion(repeticion)

    # En la primera se cargan 4 imágenes iguales (4 dragones por ejemplo) y 
    # una de ellas aparece con un tamaño distinto, reflejada en horizontal o 
    # reflejada en vertical. Esto se repite tres veces con distintas imágenes.
    def fase_1(self):
        self.fase_1_imgs = []

    def fase_1_repeticion(self, repeticion):
        global letra_sel
        letra_img = busca_letra_img(letra_sel)
        # evitar que se repita la misma imagen
        while letra_img in self.fase_1_imgs:
            letra_img = busca_letra_img(letra_sel)
        self.fase_1_imgs.append(letra_img)

        grid = self.ids["grid"]
        for but in grid.children:
            but.letra_img = letra_img
            
        
        elegido = choice(grid.children)
        elegido.efecto = choice(FXs_fase1)
        self.intruso = elegido

    # En la segunda parte se cargan cuatro burbujas con letra, 
    # tres con la letra que estamos trabajando y una cuarta con 
    # otra letra aleatoria, se repite tres veces y la letra aleatoria 
    # debe ser distinta cada vez.
    def fase_2(self): 
        global letra_sel
        self.fase_2_abecedario = abecedario_sin(letra_sel)

    def fase_2_repeticion(self, repeticion):
        global letra_sel
        letras = list(letra_sel*3)
        letra_nueva = choice(self.fase_2_abecedario)
        letras.append(letra_nueva)
        random.shuffle(letras)

        grid = self.ids["grid"]
        for but,letra in zip(grid.children, letras):
            but.letra_img = letra_img_burbuja(letra)
            if letra == letra_nueva: self.intruso = but
            but.efecto = FX_NONE

        # quita la letra usada para que no se repita
        self.fase_2_abecedario.pop(self.fase_2_abecedario.index(letra_nueva))

    # Por último, se cargan 4 burbujas con la letra que estamos trabajando pero 
    # una de ellas se carga con un tamaño distinto, reflejada en horizontal o 
    # reflejada en vertical, teniendo en cuenta que hay letras que son iguales
    # en su reflejo horizontal, o en el vertical, o en ambos.
    def fase_3(self):
        global letra_sel
        letra_img = letra_img_burbuja(letra_sel)

        grid = self.ids["grid"]
        for but in grid.children:
            but.letra_img = letra_img

    def fase_3_repeticion(self, repeticion):
        if self.intruso: self.intruso.efecto = FX_NONE
        grid = self.ids["grid"]
        but = choice(grid.children)
        but.efecto = choice(FXs_fase3)
        self.intruso = but

class CazaApp(App):
    def on_start(self):
        self.root.enter_game()

    def build(self):
        print("Build CazaApp")
        #Window.fullscreen = 'auto'
        caza = ContainerCaza()
        return caza
    
letra_sel = "b"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    CazaApp().run()
```

.kv

```
<ButOpcion>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 250, 250
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: self.letra_img
            
<BrujaProgreso>:
    Image:
        source: 'data/img/bruja.png'
        size_hint: 0.45, 0.45
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.18, "center_y": 0.5}

<Target>:
    Image:
        source: 'data/img/caldero.png'
        size_hint: 0.45, 0.45
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.9, "center_y": 0.5}
            
<ContainerCaza>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'data/img/fondobosque.jpg'
    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Ahora debes localizar al intruso entre estas imágenes. ¡Fíjate bien, una de las imágenes es distinta!'
            size_hint_y: None
            text_size: self.width, None
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'middle'
            padding: (20,15)
            font_size: 25
            color: (.66, .38, .14, 1)
            canvas.after:
                Line:
                    rectangle: self.x+1,self.y+1,self.width-1,self.height-1
                    dash_offset: 5
                    dash_length: 3
        
        GridLayout:
            id: grid
            cols: 4
            spacing: '10dp'
            canvas.after:
                Line:
                    rectangle: self.x+1,self.y+1,self.width-1,self.height-1
                    dash_offset: 5
                    dash_length: 3  
        BoxLayout:
            id: progreso
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            canvas.after:
                Line:
                    rectangle: self.x+1,self.y+1,self.width-1,self.height-1
                    dash_offset: 5
                    dash_length: 3
        
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Button:
                size_hint:.06, 0.1
                text: "Volver al menú"
                on_release: app.root.current = 'menu'          
            #Label:
                #size_hint_y: None
                #font_size: 25
                #text: "Fase %d, Repetición: %d" % (root.fase, root.repeticion) if root.fase != 0 else "FIN"
```

[image: Places]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `BrujaProgreso` and `Target` extend `Widget`, so they do not honor things like `pos_hint`. One way to fix it is to just change those two classes to extend some `Layout` (perhaps `FloatLayout`).

Another is to just have those two classes extend `Image` (`kivy.uix.image.Image`):

```
class BrujaProgreso(Image):
    pass

class Target(Image):
    pass
```

and change the `kv`:

```
<BrujaProgreso>:
    source: 'data/img/bruja.png'
    size_hint: 0.45, 0.45
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.18, "center_y": 0.5}

<Target>:
    source: 'data/img/caldero.png'
    size_hint: 0.45, 0.45
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.9, "center_y": 0.5}
```

You may need to add:

```
allow_stretch: True
keep_ratio: True
```

to those two `kv` rules.